# iOS 7 SDK view from bottom like maps app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

Could anybody please inform me which type of view is shown in the iOS 7 maps app when you touch the small info button in the right bottom corner? It only covers half the screen and I want to reuse it, but have no clue what to search for.

Thanks

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be a [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thnx :-). thought it was map-specific view or something. i actually used actionsheets in ios6, but did not recognize it because mine are red, because they show up for a delete only.